# Why isn't my "validate" method determining if my Ruby model is valid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm on Rails 5.0.  I'm confused about how to evalute whether I have a valid model.  I have a model with this method

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  validate :valid_method

   def valid_method
     false
   end
```

Notice that I have hard-coded "false" in my valid method, but even when I create an object of this class, and call "obj.valid?", I will get "true" even though I have rigged things so that the model should never be valid.  What else do I need to do to get my "valid_method" method considered when determining if a model is valid?

Comment: if you go to http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validate, you'll notice you need to add `errors` collection an error saying what happened. That's how `validate` should be used.

Comment: As @fanta points out, unless you can give a reason in the form of errors it's presumed to be a valid model.

Comment: The API docs also mention: _"Note that the return value of validation methods is not relevant."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
  validate :valid_method

   def valid_method
     errors.add(:foo, "is not valid") if some_condition?
   end
```

The return value of a validator method does not matter, what matters is that it adds an error to the [errors object](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html) (which is a hash like object).

Basically `.valid?` runs the validations and then checks if `self.errors.any?`.

Answer (score 0):

Custom validations work by checking for a custom validation and then adding an error if it fails.

This is taken from [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations)

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  validate :expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past,
    :discount_cannot_be_greater_than_total_value

  def expiration_date_cannot_be_in_the_past
    if expiration_date.present? && expiration_date < Date.today
      errors.add(:expiration_date, "can't be in the past")
    end
  end

  def discount_cannot_be_greater_than_total_value
    if discount > total_value
      errors.add(:discount, "can't be greater than total value")
    end
  end
end
```